# Displaying Zoo Visitor Results with Super Search

Tags: solspace, zoo-visitor, supersearch

I am currently trying to impliment a search of my Zoo Visiter entries; my channel is called Associate. As my title for this support request would suggest, I have Super Search installed on my site as my search engine of choice. I have tried multiple configurations using Super Search with no luck. Is it possible for me to display these member entries as search results? Am I doing this incorrectly, or is this just not possible?

My results code is below for reference:

```
{exp:super_search:results channel="associate" limit="10" group="Associate" keyword_search_author_name="yes" author_indicator="screen_name" partial_author="yes" paginate="bottom"}
  {if super_search_no_results}
   <div class="result">
    <h3>No Results Found</h3>
    <div class="content">
     There were no results found for your search.
    </div>
   </div>
  {/if}
  <div class="item {switch='lightblue|teal|orange|blue|brown|green'}">
   <a href="{url_title_path=">
    <div class="title">
     {title}
    </div>
    <div class="category">
     <div class="text"><span>Insights</span> / {categories show_group="1" backspace="2"}{category_name}, {/categories}</div>
    </div>
   </a>
  </div>
  {snp_pagination}
 {/exp:super_search:results}
```

Comment: I would start this really simple. Keep only the channel and limit parameter. Display your results with `{member_firstname}` or `{visitor:member_firstname}`. Also make sure your fields are set to searchable.